# Получение определённых данных с api

Tags: java, android, api, recyclerview

Делаю приложение для поиска рецептов с помощью forkify API. Мне приходит [такой](https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/search?q=pizza) json (для примера возьмём рецепты пиццы). Я сделал ресайклер и возможность поиска, но сами рецепты даются как ссылка на сайт с тем рецептом (смотрите source_url в json). Я сделал для этого webview, но тут возникла одна проблема. Мне нужно получать тот source_url и чтоб он подходил к тому рецепту, на который я кликнул. Я попытался сделать дополнительный элемент в ресайклере, маленький невидимый textview, и засунуть туда source_url, чтоб потом при клике брать с него текст и передавать в переменную и её загружать как url в webview. (Очень глупое решение, но до другого я не додумался) У меня получилось не то, что надо. По сути мой код работает, но передаётся url не со всех textView. Я понаблюдал за его поведением и могу предположить, что загружается только каждый 4 в вертикальном и каждый 2 в горизонтальном режиме. И это не то, что мне надо. Прошу помочь решить данную проблему. Ниже мой код:

Адаптер:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import coil.load
import com.example.foodproject.BrowserActivity
import com.example.foodproject.R
import com.example.foodproject.RecyclerItemClickListener
import com.example.foodproject.model.Recipe
import com.example.foodproject.model.requestdata
import com.example.foodproject.utils.ConstandVar
import com.example.foodproject.utils.ConstandVar.food
import com.example.foodproject.viewmodel.FoodViewModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recyclerview_item_row.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.recyclerview_item_row.view.*

@JvmOverloads
fun RecyclerView.affectOnItemClicks(
    onClick: ((position: Int, view: View) -> Unit)? = null,
    onLongClick: ((position: Int, view: View) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    this.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(
        RecyclerItemClickListener(
            this,
            onClick,
            onLongClick
        )
    )
}
class RecyclerAdapter(
    private val dataset: List<Recipe>
)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.FoodHolder>() {

    inner class FoodHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun bindRecipe(recipe: Recipe) {
            itemView.textView.text = recipe.title
            itemView.textView3.text = recipe.publisher
            itemView.imageView.load(recipe.image_url) {
                // placeholder image is the image used
                // when our image url fails to load.
                placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_error_24)
            }
            itemView.helptv.text = recipe.source_url
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerAdapter.FoodHolder {
        // шаблонный код
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_row, parent, false)

        return FoodHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerAdapter.FoodHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindRecipe(dataset.get(position))

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataset.size
}
```

Код в Мейн активити где я засовываю текст из того текствью в вспомогательную переменную а потом перехожу на другое активити:

```
ConstandVar.browser_url = helptv.text.toString()
                                    val intent = Intent(this, BrowserActivity::class.java)
                                      startActivity(intent)
```

Макет ресайклера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/materialCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:state_dragged="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_constraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="publisher: The Pioner Women"
                android:textColor="#E57373"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/helptv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="1sp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Метод получения json:

```
fun getRecipe(callback: (List<Recipe>) -> Unit) {

        val apiService = AppModule.provideRetrofitInstance(ConstandVar.BASE_URL)
        apiService.getRecipe(food).enqueue(object : Callback<requestdata> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<requestdata>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("tag", "getRecipe Error")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<requestdata>, response: Response<requestdata>) {
                return response.body()!!.recipes?.let { callback(it) }!!
            }

        })
```

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Надеюсь понятно объяснил, но если что, с радостью уточню любые детали.